# architecture properties to consider when writing optimized memcopy in assembly

Tags: assembly, optimization, arm, microcontroller, memcpy

Feel free to change the title (or offer a suggestion) if it could be better.

I'm on a ARM Cortex M4 and I need to write a faster mem-copy in assembly.

**In general, what aspects of the architecture does one need to consider when writing optimized *memcopy* in assembly?**

For example: my colleague is using ARM Cortex M7 which has dual issue so he showed me how his assembly **memcopy** was written to take that into account.

Comment: Expected use case (copy size and alignment) can decide how you branch to select a loop.  Also, how much you unroll (whether to use *all* the registers to hide load latency on an in-order pipeline.)

Comment: What is wrong with the memcpy in your C library, not uncommon for them to already be hand tuned assembly.  What C library if any are you using and why do you think you can optimize it?  for a cortex-m or arm in general you want to use an ldm/stm 1 2 or 4 words, aligned.   do performance tests to see.  also will want your code aligned which you have to hand tune, but that varies by implementation.

Comment: Of course this begs the question of why. On any reasonable Cortex-M4 SOC you would have a DMA controller. Have you considered using that?

Comment: @andymango currently I’m only copying 1,2,4,8 bytes at a time though I am doing it very often. Would DMA be useful in this situation?

Comment: No, the setup would overwhelm you. But with that small amount of data in motion and if you are that concerned with speed, why use memcpy() at all.

Comment: @andymango I’m looking into refactoring my code so that I can have a contiguous chunk of memory where DMA might be useful. However, that would still require doing a bunch of 1,2,4,8 byte copies to assemble said data into a large buffer so I don’t see what I’m gaining. Am I gaining anything?

Comment: The ARM DMA controller is quite sophisticated and can do scatter/gather operations. The only real way to tell if it helps is to code it up and measure it. But that is an investment :)

Comment: @andymango one interesting thing I noticed. My current copy() implementation copies 4-byte word at a time then copies the remaining bytes not a multiple of 4-bytes. However, copy(1 byte) takes 76% more time than copy(4-byte word). I’m guessing it’s due to non-aligned memory access?